# Support Actionbar Icon overlay ActionbarDivider

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

i try to fix a bug in my app.
In case of that i have to change my ActionBar to the SupportActionbar!

[image]

But now my icon overlays the divider. 
And the TitleText is away can u help me?

Thank you!

Styles:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="myActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abc_ab_transparent_dark_holo</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: How are you displaying logo in support theme?

Comment: by android:label="@....", in Manifest, in "application"-Tag

Comment: Are you displaying logo with android:label ?? Try android:logo..., Also try getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true); in activity